# html/php forms with survey database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I hope someone can help me! I try to make a form with input from mysql. I want a statement to come from a database. Following this I want a user to be able to give a value 1-7(strongly disagree - strongly agree). I want the number of questions be based on my MySQL query. The main reason for this is that I can reuse the code for different types of surveys.

The problem is: I can't get the questions into a single form with separated values, linked to the question. I'm guessing it has something to do with the name= part. I think the name should be related to the database query somehow but I can't find out what the solution is.

If someone could help me I would be very thankful. Also if someone knows a good book or online course/video explaining how to make a online survey tool it would be very helpful.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <?php 
    echo '<form action="results.php" method="post">';
    global $connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["question"];
        echo "<br>";
        echo '  <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=1>
                <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=2>
                <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=3>
                <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=4>
                <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=5>
                <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=6>
                <input type="radio" name="likkert" value=7>
                <br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo '<input type="submit"></form>';
    ?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? The saving into the database? Showing the result?

Comment: Try to include your connection file at the first line and check if you get the results.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick responses! The problem is that in this way the user can check the radio button but for one line, but if he checkes the next line it will uncheck the previous line. This is because the radio button is named "likkert" for all the questions. Instead I think I must include the question ID somehow into the name. But for this I don't know the right syntax.

Comment: By the way, the connection is not the problem as I get all my questions. Thanks anyhow for the response!

Comment: @NielsvanLeeuwen I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thanks! this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the fact that you have an *id* column, associated with each question, in `questions` table, you have to include this *id* column value (which should be unique) with each question's rating options, like this:

```
// your code
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["question"];
        echo "<br />";
        ?>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=1>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=2>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=3>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=4>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=5>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=6>
        <input type="radio" name="likkert[<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>]" value=7>
        <br />
        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
// your code
```

And after form submission, process the questions and their corresponding ratings like this:

```
foreach($_POST['likkert'] as $questionId => $rating){
    // your code
}
```